# Using python and numpy, how to convert 1d list to a list of np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

Here is the input:

```
input_list=[a,b,c,d]
```

I hope to get output

```
output_list=[np.array([a]),np.array([b]),np.array([c]),np.array([d])]
```

I know that a loop on each element should also work, but I wonder whether is there quick method to complete this? Thanks in advance.

---

Here is my code for three method, there are no big difference in speed, but the 2nd & 3rd is much neater. :

1st method: `t.append(np.array([i]))` , cost_time= `14.1404731274 seconds`

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
for index, row in modified_test_store_raw_df[modified_test_store_raw_df.Open==1].iterrows():
    input_value=(list(modified_test_store_raw_df.loc[index,'tuple_map']))
    t=[]
    for i in input_value:
        t.append(np.array([i])) 
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

2nd method: `t=[np.array([x]) for x in input_value]` , cost_time= `13.7779290676 seconds`

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
for index, row in modified_test_store_raw_df[modified_test_store_raw_df.Open==1].iterrows():
    input_value=(list(modified_test_store_raw_df.loc[index,'tuple_map']))
    t=[np.array([x]) for x in input_value]
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

3rd method: `t=np.array(input_value)[:, None]` , cost_time= `13.2799420357 seconds`

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
for index, row in modified_test_store_raw_df[modified_test_store_raw_df.Open==1].iterrows():
    input_value=(list(modified_test_store_raw_df.loc[index,'tuple_map']))
    t=np.array(input_value)[:, None]
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Everyone is suggesting a list comprehension, which of course is a list loop.  That's basically it. As long as your goal is a list that's a quick as it gets.  `numpy` functions will produce an array of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
[np.array([x]) for x in input_list]
```

But maybe you need this instead:

```
np.array(input_list)[:, None]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your 2nd approach. It puts everything in a single array, whereas OP wants different array for each element in the list.

Comment: If the elements are lists of differing size, the 2nd will produce an object array of lists, not a list of arrays.  If they are all 1d lists of the same size, the result will be a 2d array.  Only if they are scalars will the `None` help.

Comment: @kmario23 Yeah. The 2nd option is just a guess of what OP may want.

Comment: @hpaulj That's what I am assuming. a 1d list is more appropriate if it is a list of scalars.

Comment: `np.array(input_list)[:, None]  ` is the neatest method.

Answer (score 0):

How about a using a list comprehension?

```
output_list = [ np.array([item]) for item in input_list]
```

Or the much better generator comprehension:

```
output_gen = (np.array([item]) for item in input_list)
```